# 'yarn set version berry' command fails with ETIMEDOUT, though having proxy config in .yarnrc

Tags: yarnpkg

Running command ´yarn set version berry´ behind corporate proxy complains with Error : Request Error: connect ETIMEDOUT XXX.XX.XXX.XXX:443

[Timeout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWxwu.png)

I have set proxy through npm as well as yarn. ´npm install -g yarn´ worked pretty well. Basically I have two file ´.npmrc´ and ´.yarnrc´ to handle this.

Yarn config looks like :

[Yarn config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bone3.png)